# Design pattern to limit access to a class's public members in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++17

All of the code below is pseudo-code, for the sake of brevity.

Consider an event system, where have the following class:

```
class Event_dispatcher {
private:
    Listener_collection listeners;

public:
    void add_listener(Listener _listener) { ... }
    void remove_listener(Listener _listener) { ... }
    void post_event(Event _event) { ... }
};
```

I intend to have instances of `Event_dispatcher` in classes that are meant to send out events. However, I only want the events to be posted from inside the class, so that the user can only add or remove listeners, but never post events.
The simple solution would be to make `Event_dispatcher` a private member of the enclosing class, but then, I have to define `add_listener` and `remove_listener` as public members that forward the argument to the event dispatcher.
I am aware that two methods do not seem like a lot, but please bear in mind, **this is just an example**, I made it short on purpose. Imagine the same problem where I would have to define a significantly greater number of methods in a similar fashion.

I am trying to find out if there is a common or recommended way of solving problems like this. A solution that came to my mind would be to define an interface class like this:

```
class Event_dispatcher_interface {
private:
    Event_dispatcher* event_dispatcher;

public:
    void add_listener(Listener _listener) { event_dispatcher->add_listener(_listener); }
    void remove_listener(Listener _listener) { event_dispatcher->remove_listener(_listener); }
};
```

and make this a public member of the enclosing class. The pointer inside (`*event_dispatcher`) would point to the `Event_dispatcher` that's a private member of the enclosing class, so as to only allow for posting events from inside the class.

If there are other (better) solutions, I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: You might look at the ROS2 and DDS or other "pub/sub" APIs.

Comment: "*I intend to have instances of Event_dispatcher in classes that are meant to send out events. However, I only want the events to be posted from inside the class, so that the user can only add or remove listeners, but never post events.*" Inside of which class? `Event_dispatcher` or some other class?

Comment: "in classes that are meant to send out events"
Sorry if this wasn't worded very clearly. Imagine a class that receives keyboard input, for example. I would like to have an instance of `Event_dispatcher` inside. The user can subscribe to this event dispatcher, to receive a notification when a key is pressed.

Comment: There are several ways to "play" with visibility, not clear exactly what you want.

Comment: I don't think I can explain it more clearly then - I'm sorry.

Comment: You probably spent more time writing this question than you'd ever save fixing any "bugs" introduced if you didn't try so hard to engineer out the potential for hacks you don't approve of. Just a thought.

Comment: @stackoverflow_account_23492384: You wrote *"I only want the events to be posted from inside the class"* but then *"I forgot to mention in the question that this is not the only way I would like to use this class."* It seems to be you change your mind :/

Comment: [Attorney-client idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Friendship_and_the_Attorney-Client) might interest you.

Comment: Exactly. I didn't really *change my mind*, but I did indeed fail to include all the necessary details in this question, and that's why this whole discussion came out a bit messy. I'm new to participating on stackoverflow, so that might be why.
Either way, I really appreciate all the answers I've received on this question, I found what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

You might use inheritance to inherit from visibility

```
class Event_dispatcher {
private:
    Listener_collection listeners;
public:
    void add_listener(Listener _listener) { ... }
    void remove_listener(Listener _listener) { ... }
protected:
    void post_event(Event _event) { ... }
};
```

then

```
struct MyClass : Event_dispatcher
{
    // accessible as public
    // void add_listener(Listener _listener);
    // void remove_listener(Listener _listener);

    // only usage from within the class
    //void post_event(Event _event);
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Your solution, however, makes it impossible *everywhere* to post events to `Event_dispatcher` from outside the enclosing class - I forgot to mention in the question that this is not the only way I would like to use this class.

Comment: @stackoverflow_account_23492384 Always and never are easy. Some of the time... That gets tricky and requires more details. `friend`ship probably won't scale, but an abstraction layer might.

Comment: Yes, that's what I would like to achieve. But as I understand it, there doesn't seem to be a universal solution to this. I suppose some kind of wrapper (like the one I posted in the original question, or perhaps one using inheritance) seems like a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This approach relies on *delegation* and *friendship*.

You can make all `Event_dispatcher` member functions private and *grand friendship* to individual classes that would access those member functions instead:

```
class Event_dispatcher {
   friend class Listener_manager;
   friend class Event_poster;

   // all private
   void add_listener(Listener _listener) { /* */ }
   void remove_listener(Listener _listener) { /* */ }
   void post_event(Event _event) { /* */ }

   Listener_collection listeners;
};
```

Then, define `Listener_manager` and `Event_poster` classes that provides access to `add_listener()` / `remove_listener()` and `post_event()`, respectively. They both rely on *delegation*:

```
struct Listener_manager {
   Listener_manager(Event_dispatcher& ed): dispatcher(ed) {}   
   void add_listener(Listener _listener) {
      dispatcher.add_listener(_listener);
   }
   void remove_listener(Listener _listener) {
      dispatcher.remove_listener(_listener);
   }
private:
   Event_dispatcher& dispatcher;
};

struct Event_poster {
   Event_poster(Event_dispatcher& ed): dispatcher(ed) {}
   void post_event(Event _event) { dispatcher.post_event(_event); }
private:
   Event_dispatcher& dispatcher;
};
```

In your class, declare objects of these classes as data members. You can control the accessibilty of each member individually:

```
struct MyClass {
public:
   MyClass(): listener(dispatcher), poster(dispatcher) {}
private:
   Event_dispatcher dispatcher;
public: // accessible from the outside
   Listener_manager listener_manager; // add_listener()/remove_listener()
private:
   Event_poster event_poster; // post_event()
};
```

You could call `add_listener()` and `remove_listener()` as:

```
MyClass obj;

obj.listener.add_listener(listener);
obj.listener.remove_listener(listener);
```

Since the member `event_poster` is private, its member function `post_event()` can only be accessed inside `MyClass`.

---

#### Using CRTP

Instead, you can keep the original accessibility of the members of your `Event_dispatcher` class, and define the following class template, `Accessor<>`, which will handle the delegating part:

```
template<typename T>
class Accessor {
public:
   void add_listener(Listener _listener) {
      static_cast<T&>(*this).event_dispatcher.add_listener(_listener);
   }

   void remove_listener(Listener _listener) {
      static_cast<T&>(*this).event_dispatcher.remove_listener(_listener);
   }
};
```

Then, publicly inherit from this class template instantiated on the defining class itself (i.e., [*CRTP*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)):

```
struct MyClass: Accessor<MyClass> {
   friend class Accessor<MyClass>;

private:
   Event_dispatcher event_dispatcher;
};
```

You still need to grant friendship to the base class so that it can access the private data member `event_dispatcher` – and this member must have this name.

This way, you can access `Event_dispatcher::add_listener()` and `Event_dispatcher::remove_listener()` in a more concise way:

```
MyClass obj;   

obj.add_listener(listener);
obj.remove_listener(listener);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like this solution, it seems a bit similar to the one I posted in the original question if I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: @stackoverflow_account_23492384 The last edit of the answer, which uses CRTP, is probably more convenient.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, the CRTP solution is very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is friend classes:

cplusplus.com has a good [page on this](http://www.cplusplus.com/)

TLDR;
When you specify class B as a friend of class A, class B has full access to the private functions of class A.

Try this:

```cpp
class Outer_Class {
    public:
        Event_dispatcher my_event_dispatcher;
        // whatever else is public
    
    private:
        void example_func();
};

class Event_dispatcher {
    friend class Outer_Class;
    private:
        Listener_collection listeners;
        void post_event(Event _event) { ... }

    public:
        void add_listener(Listener _listener) { ... }
        void remove_listener(Listener _listener) { ... }
};

void Outer_Class::example_func(){
   // In here, you can use the functions from the class that made it a friend
   my_event_dispatcher.post_event(my_event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Now I see I really should have mentioned this in the question, but I forgot - this prevents `Event_dispatcher` from being usable for posting events from outside the enclosing class. I don't want to get rid of that functionality - I only want to be able to selectively limit it.
(I also heard that cplusplus.com is a source that should be avoided... But I'm not an expert, I don't want to judge.)

Comment: May also be worth noting that the friended class / function will also be able to see the private members of the original class.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "selectively limit". Do you mean having Event_Dispatcher inherited by a large number of classes, where some have access to post_event and others dont?